# What ever happened to OpenSSO?

Tags: java, opensso

OpenSSO is referenced in a lot of JBoss and Sun/Oracle documentation, but the project appears to have vanished. Even the [Wikipedia OpenSSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSO) page links to dead home pages. What ever happened to the project? Has it been renamed or merged into another project?

Comment: the first two paragraphs of that wiki page seem to explain what happened

Comment: @guido sometimes people seem to like other people to read stuff for them ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.forgerock.com/openam.html